# how to use dynamic routes in nextjs and accessing params in the second page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

how to use dynamic routes in `nextjs` and accessing params in the second page

here is what the pages structure looks like :

[image]

My Code :

**/jobs/[id]/index.tsx**

```
"use client"
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

export default   function JobDetails({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const [job, setJob] = useState<any[] | null>([])
  console.log(params) 

  async function fetchJobDetails() {
    const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey);
    const { data: fetchedJob } = await supabase
    .from('jobs')
    .select("*")
    .eq('id', params.id)
    setJob(fetchedJob)
    }
    fetchJobDetails()

  return (
    <div>
        <p>asd</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**jobsTable.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Paper, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow } from '@mui/material'
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function JobsTable() {

  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState<any[] | null>([])

  async function fetchCountries() {
    const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey);
    const { data: fetchedJobs } = await supabase.from("jobs").select("*,cities!inner(*)");
    setJobs(fetchedJobs)
  }
  fetchCountries();


  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label='simple table'>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Title En|AR</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {jobs?.map((job: any) =>
          (
            <TableRow
              key={job.id}
              sx={{
                '&:last-of-type td, &:last-of-type th': {
                  border: 0
                }
              }}
            >
              <Link href={`/jobs/${job.id}`} passHref>
              <TableCell component='th' scope='row'>
                {job.title_en} |  {job.title_ar}
              </TableCell>
              </Link>
            </TableRow>
          )


          )}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>

  )
}
```

But I am unable to catch `params` at all. the output of `console.log(params)`  is always undefined

Comment: if i'm not mistaken query param on client could be retreaved with hook const { id } = useRouter()?.query